# R condition loop. Error takes only the first element

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am using this double condition to get an output in a new column, but it gives me only the first match and not all that match the conditions.
In the third and fourth line in the column "scores2" hast to be 0,2 and not 0.
It would be great if someone can help me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
id  touchpoint_ts   tp_type Referrer    scores  scores2
1   31.10.2017 05:09    a   4   1,7 0
1   13.10.2017 03:19    b   2   0,1 0,2
1   12.10.2017 06:19    b   2   0,1 0
1   12.10.2017 06:19    b   2   0,1 0
1   12.10.2017 06:19    b   0   0,1 0
1   08.09.2017 14:26    a   3   3   0

dataset$scores2<-c(0)
for (i in 1:length(dataset$id)){
  if (dataset$tp_type[i] == "b"){
    while ((dataset$Referrer[i]) > 1){
      dataset$scores2[i]=dataset$scores[i]*2
    } } else {
      dataset$scores2[i]=0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A problem is here:

```
 while ((dataset$Referrer[i]) > 1){
      dataset$scores2[i]=dataset$scores[i]*2
    }
```

This is a while-true because your condition will be valid forever.

Try to use this approach, your conditions:

```
cond1<-dataset$tp_type == "b" & dataset$Referrer>1
cond2<-dataset$tp_type == "b" & dataset$Referrer<=1
```

Applications:

```
dataset[cond1,"scores2"]<-dataset[cond1,"scores"]*2
dataset[cond2,"scores2"]<-0
```

Comment: You are welcome, acceptance of the answer is welcome.